# JavaScript :how do i print the lack of numbers in Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I want to build an Array , the Array's element is 1 to N+1 , 
and find out what the number is lack?

for example: [1,3,4,5],should print 2

example:

```
function solution(arr) {
    // find the missing number and return
}

console.log(solution([1,3,4,5])); // 2
```

Comment: Hi Simon, welcome to stackoverflow. In order to help you, we would like to see what you have tried so far.

Comment: I won't give you the code, but you simply need to check the value against the index+1 in a for loop or with forEach.

Comment: actually I have no idea to start

Comment: can you use 3rd party libs??

Comment: @ΦXoce웃Пepeúpa there is no need for the libs. Job is simple enough to code it yourself.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/pupagaqeze/edit?js,console => I've tried on this site , not done ,could give me some advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use [`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), because it can return a variable amount of missing items in an array.

```js
function missing(r, a, i, aa) {
    var n = aa[i - 1] + 1;
    while (n < a) {
        r.push(n++);
    }
    return r;
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify([1, 3, 4, 5].reduce(missing, []), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify([0, 5].reduce(missing, []), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify([1, 2, 3].reduce(missing, []), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var size = arr.length;
var last_num = arr[length-1];
var missing = "";
for (var i = 1; i<last_num; i++){
   if (arr.indexOf(i)<0){
      missing += i;
   }
}
console.log(missing);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = [1,3,4,5];
for (var i=0; i<=array.length-1; i++) {
    if (i+1 != array[i]) {
        return i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this) so simlpe task - I think you can do it by yourself but))

```
var solution = function (array) { 
      array.map(function (item,i) { 
        if((array[i+1] - array[i]) > 1) 
           console.log(array[i] + 1) }) 
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [lodash](https://lodash.com/) or can include it to your project, the following will work:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8];
var diff = _.difference(_.range(Math.min.apply(Math, arr), Math.max.apply(Math, arr)), arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
function miss_val(k){
   var n=k.length+1;
   var sum=n*(n+1)/2;
   var sum2=k.reduce(function(a,b){return(a+b)});
   var miss=sum-sum2;
   console.log(miss);


}
miss_val([1,2,3,5]);
```